# Como abrir URL externa em modal bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-3, url, modal

Já uso o modal bootstrap e ele funcionou muito bem para o conteúdo que testei. Mas não encontro nada que explique como abrir uma pagina externa em um modal no site.
Alguem sabe como fazer?
Fico grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="http://www.bing.com" data-target="#myModal">click me</a>


<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
});
```

no caso você terá que usar um iframe veja funcionando no jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3LkL/84/